# How to pray for something

Tags: tefilla

How is one supposed to pray for something he needs?

Is he/she supposed to request it from God once or repeat the request over and over, or make arguments why he deserves it or something else?

It says for example that Isaac and Rebeca prayed years for a son. Did they just sit in a corner and repeat the request over and over again?

(update: looking more for a source from books that instructs on how to do this rather than the experiences of an individual in tanach)

Comment: This is pretty much the subject of R. Shimshon Dovid Pincus' entire sefer, Shaarei Tefillah (highly recommended even though it's rather unusual)

Comment: But his answer to the last question is yes, often times the appropriate way to pray is merely to repeat the same request over and over

Comment: @Matt ok thanks matt. is the book online?

Comment: @Matt do you mean shaarim b'tefillah?

Comment: @YEZ yeah sorry that was a typo. And no it's not online, but it is on otzar hachachma

Comment: @ray see my edited answer below, and please listen to the shiur, I think it will answer your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Shafier (of [*The Shmuz*](http://www.theshmuz.com/)) says that the best way to pray for something specific is to realize that G-d is in control of everything, and human beings are not.

When a person realizes how incredibly helpless he or she is without G-d , he or she will cry out to G-d for assistance, in very simple terms, the way that a young child cries out to parents to have his or her needs met.

You can listen to the shiur by clicking the link below, and pressing play on the on-screen audio player:  no sign up or download required.

[Click here for Shumuz #236 by Rav Ben Tzion Shafier](http://www.theshmuz.com/shmuz/236-talk-hashem-listens/)

Comment: I listened to the shiur again, and edited my answer to include a summary.

Comment: Great, +1! That was really nice of you :)

Comment: thank you jake. according to this answer, how do you think rivka and issac prayed for a son for 10+ years. did they just keep on talking like a child repeating the same words?

Comment: @ray I don't know, but I also know that I'm not rivka or yitzchak, and I never will be.

Comment: very good shiur. said alot about the importance of prayer and that it helps, but i did not find that it addresses the point of how to pray. ok, it says make a request, but when that is done, then what? do you keep repeating the same request over and over, or do you try to find new types of arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Rebbe Nachman of Breslov has many specific teachings on prayer. He taught that one should speak to Hashem in one's own words for at least an hour each day, thanking and praising Him, doing teshuvah, asking to come close to Him, and asking for any material or spiritual things we need. Though the main emphasis in much of his writings is on praying about spiritual matters, Rebbe Nachman also taught that one should pray for any physical thing one needs, even something as insignificant as a missing button on one's coat. Here is one paragraph partially summarizing his approach:

"It has already been explained how important it is to seclude yourself and pray, and how powerful a method this is. It is the path by which we can come close to God. Everybody should set aside fixed periods every day and express himself before God in his own native language. It is much easier to say what you need to say when you are using your own language. **You should set forth whatever is in your heart. Use every kind of appeal and argument. Use words that will endear you to God and win His favor.** Plead with Him to draw you closer. Every individual knows his own personal pain and sorrow and the distance that separates him from God. It is impossible to convey the true greatness of this method. It is superior to all others. It is the way of serving God, and through following it everyone can attain the ultimate good in this world and in the World to Come. **There is nothing that cannot be accomplished by prayer and entreaty.** The greatest of the Tzaddikim achieved what they did only through this practice. Think about it carefully and you will see the greatness of this path. Set aside one hour every day for this, the rest of the day be happy -- and then you will be truly blessed." (Likutei Eitzot, Hitbodedut).

More can be found here: http://www.azamra.org/Advice/meditation.html and here: http://www.azamra.org/Advice/prayer.html and here: www.azamra.org/Essential/hisbodedus.htm

Rabbi Shalom Arush, a Breslover Rosh Yeshivah in Israel, has two additional teachings regarding praying for a particular thing. If one is in need of something very important, he teaches that one should pray for six hours straight for that thing, or for an hour a day for that thing for a whole month. He reports many miraculous salvations resulting from this practice, as described in his books and articles.

Comment: is this a chidush of breslov or are there sources from chazal?

Comment: Rav Arush cite some sources in his book In Forest Fields. The general idea of praying in one's own words obviously occurs in Torah and Tanakh, Rambam says this was the original mode of prayer, and there are examples of Tannaim in the Gemara praying spontaneously in their own words. Rebbe Nachman claims that the great tzaddikim throughout history achieved their spiritual levels through similar practices. That said, some aspects of the Breslov approach are probably new, or at least written down for the first time in Rebbe Nachaman's and Reb Noson's teachings.

Answer (score 1):

Chazal tell us that Moshe Rabbenu davened to go into Eretz Yisroel 515 times.

Comment: it also says isaac and rivka prayed years for a son, but what happened at those sessions.

Comment: @ray - He is answering part of your question, whether to request once or many times.

Comment: Do you know where Chazal say that?  If so, editing it into your answer would make it stronger.

Comment: The question remains: Did Moshe Rebeinu (alav hashalom) repeat the same text as a mantra or did he change his wording each time?

Comment: I answered the question regarding the request. Why do you think that changing the text / wording would change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Chafetz Chaim - Likutei Amarim ch.11

> "In summation, all the many calamities that come on us and that we are
>   not saved from them is because we are not screaming and outpouring in
>   prayer over them. If we would pray and would pour out before HaKadosh
>   Baruch Hu, certainly our prayers and supplications would not return
>   empty. And it's not enough for a person to pray the shemonei esrei
>   three times a day, rather a few times per day, a person needs to pour
>   out prayers and supplications in solitude, in his house, from the
>   depths of his heart. Because the three prayers (shemonei esrei) are
>   already fixed in his mouth and he doesn't take them to heart so much.
>   But if a person would contemplate in solitude and make a cheshbon
>   hanefesh on his personal situation, his great poverty and his many
>   toils, and for all this to live on crusty bread and water, then he
>   will pour out his heart like water in front of Hashem, yisborach, and
>   the prayer will go out with deep kavana and with a broken heart and a
>   lowly spirit. A prayer like this will certainly not return empty. And
>   then when his soul is bitter on him, on his situation and his weak
>   standing, and he drops supplications before HaKadosh Baruch Hu, he
>   should also remember the great pain of Hashem yisborach, because he
>   also, so to speak, does not have rest. In all our suffering He
>   suffers..."

comes down to the verse "pour out your heart like water in the presence of the Lord" - Lamentations 2:19

there is no "technique" for this for that would miss the point

Answer (score 0):

My prayers have been answered many times. I think of Rabbi Nachman and his advise, I pray in silence or in tears, secluded in my car, or in my room, or walking in the park. I thank hashem for his kindness, for his blessings, and I accept that the solution is in his hands. I am machmir of mitzvot, especially brachot and tzedakah, and await the best, for it is sure to come.

Comment: Thank you for the post, but I don't think it directly answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going with the Avraham praying for Sdom route. Each time he was rejected he tried a different approach. Both mathematically and as far as 'reasoning' with Hashem 'chalila licha etc'.
 I would also guess that Chana's promise to give her first child over to Hashem was the first time she tried that.

Comment: avraham was praying but also having a two way conversation. what are we supposed to do? think up as many arguments as we can?

Comment: I would think so. Now that i think of it thats what Choni hamaagal did, that's what rabi Akiva did when he started saying Avinu Malkeinu. Think of a good reason why you think Hashem should do something and tell it to Him.

Comment: OP specified he wants sources addressing this explicitly; not stories from Tanakh.

Comment: @user6591 No need to get mean. Maybe he just didn’t notice. Be that as it may, maybe you could improve your answer to reflect the new version of the question?

Comment: This post had non-positive score at the time the question was edited, so changes to the question can invalidate it such that it should be deleted. You should consider updating your post to match the question or just deleting it (and maybe adding some of its content as a comment above).

Comment: see too https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759

Comment: @Double Note I didn't say Mevaqesh had no right to downvote my answer. Note also as a moderator that there are numerous other answers here which suffer the same lack of adhering to the preference edited into the question which he did not downvote. Those answers were given after the edit. He even commented on one. But he only downvoted mine. This is a problem. A recurring one that I've brought up with  moderator before.